# How many NVMe SSDs can I connect to a desktop PC and how?

Tags: ssd, raid, nvme, raid-10

I have 25 NVMe 2230 SSDs, each of them 256 GB. I was wondering how many of them can be connected to my desktop PC somehow. I know there are some adapters like quad NVMe to PCI-E but I want to use a lot more than 4 of them. I have ROG Crosshair VIII Hero as motherboard. What are the methods to use them without using dedicated slots on motherboard?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You cannot span a partition across physical drives, so you have a bunch of tiny pieces.

Comment: @John You can with LVM or RAID or some filesystems like ZFS and btrfs.

Comment: I assumed the OP did not have a RAID setup for the environment they have.

Comment: @Alpay, you can salvage this question by [edit]-ing it to ask how to connect the drives. That would make it a problem-based question, rather that a brainstorm topic/poll. You may want to specify how many drives you want to connect exactly or make maximizing that number a part of the question.

Comment: @john decent OS's have had software raid as part of the base OS for well over 20 years.

Comment: With low cost of 250 gig SSDs I'd suggest that its not worthwhile to build an array out of them.  You can get NVME USB enclosures + usb hubs but it becomes expensive and unweildy and only gives a fraction if the perfornance.

Comment: Give them to a good cause running clapped out hdd'sfor office/web browsing (if the data on them is not valuable)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Step 1. you need 4 of these.

Uses 8 x OCuLink (SFF - 8612) to connect, pin-out defined by SFF - 9402 Rev 1.1

Step 2.  You need to buy a RAID controller with OCuLink support.